# Handlebars single json item and #each

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I have a simple node app that returns a single item from my mySQL database as json, but I can't render the data in my Handlebars template, without using the {{#each}} tag, but that shouldn't be necessary?

Here is the server code

```js
app.get("/get-car/:id", function (req, res) {
    const carSql = `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    const carQuery = db.query(carSql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
        //res.render("partials/car", results);
    });
});
```

That simply returns this json

```js
[
 {
  id: 120,
  userId: 1,
  brand: "Honda",
  model: "Civic",
  year: "2018"
 }
]
```

If I then send the data to my template, I would think that it should be possible to just write {{brand}} fx., but that returns nothing. If I then wrap it in a {{#each}} it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it in object notation since you know the position in the `results` array:

```
{{results[0].brand}}
```

`[0]` selects the first index of that array.

Comment: That did the trick! Tho it had to be {{[0].brand}} since I don't have the content wrapped in "results". Didn't know that syntax, thanks :)